# Destroying a session in koa-session

Tags: koa

So I have a simple authorization system where on login user is saved to a session. Problem is in situation like that, where I want to delete a session, thus logging the user out, session carries onto the next request.

```
app.get('/logout', ctx => {
    ctx.session = null;
    ctx.redirect('/');
});
```

So in this situation code below will render user info on the page after redirecting from logout:

```
app.get('/', ctx => ctx.body = ctx.session);
```

Cookies aren't cleared too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly new to [koa-session](https://github.com/koajs/session) but was able to implement user authentication in a project a while back, by setting the user's id object to `ctx.session.id`.

### Login

```js
router.post('/login', async ctx => {
  const userDetails = ctx.request.body
  try {
        const userDetails = ctx.request.body
        const userId = await user.login(userDetails)
        ctx.session.authenticated = true
        ctx.session.id = userId
        ctx.redirect('/')
    } catch (error) {
        await ctx.render('login', {error: error})
    } finally {
        await user.tearDown()
    }
})
```

### Logout

```js
router.get('/logout', async ctx => {
    if (ctx.session.authenticated === true) {
        ctx.session.authenticated = false
        ctx.session.id = undefined
    }
    ctx.redirect('/')
})
```

In your case, you may want to assign `ctx.session.user = userObject`, then when logging a user out, reassign to `ctx.session.user = null`.

Comment: Looks like a nice solution. Thanks!